# converting .trc 2 ascii

Tags: database, oracle

I have accidentally saved some data using the oracle TRACE file format.  I have been trying to convert these data files into normal text (ASCII) file formats for a day now without much success.  Can someone help me into the right direction? I would prefer to use linux but do also have access to a windows machine. I could upload an example file as well.  The files come from a RIGOL scope and using "vim" to peer into them gives something along the lines of: "sc8^@DS1104Z^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@00.04.01.SP2^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^E^@^[s`¢^@^@^@^@<8c><9c>^@^@^L^@^B^@^@É^C^@ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..."

Comment: Can you elaborate? When I think of a trace file, it is in ASCII, so perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: Hi I've updated the question; it is a binary format I believe, from the oracle framework

Comment: Sorry, I'm none the wiser. What command(s) did you execute to generate this fie?

Comment: I used a RIGOL scope's "save file" command.. what a pain!!

Comment: What on earth does a rigol file dump have to do with Oracle?